# Java InetAddress, NetworkInterface, ServerSocket

Tags: java, сервер, сеть, сокет, ip-address

Сделал клиент-серверное приложение, хочу запустить его в интернете. 
Все гайды по клиент-серверам основаны на одной машине либо в локальной сети, есть вопросы по поводу интернета:

Чтобы вывести сервер с любой машины в интернет(а адрес может быть и серый, а не выделенный, что чаще и бывает сегодня), то обязательно нужно прибегать к сервисам типа NoIP и другим подобным? Или есть другой способ?

Очень давно терзает данный вопрос, так как если скинуть программу-сервер другому человеку(особенно который не кодер), то он же не разберется с NoIP, хочется как то сделать так, чтобы человек просто нажал кнопку "Listen" и сервер начал прослушивать, выдавая в неком окне адрес к которому нужно подключиться.

Comment: У вас не статический IP? Вроде ж если статический, то не надо.

Comment: Можно принцип пояснить, просто если даже и статический IP, но серый, то такой IP может(и будет) одинаков с многими другими IP из интернета